# How to set yarn version configs in yarn2+?

Tags: continuous-integration, yarnpkg-v2

I am moving my project from yarn1 to yarn2+.
I'm using yarn to bump the versions of the packages in a monorepo and [setting config](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/version/) version options with a command e.g. `yarn config set version-git-message` in my ci pipeline.

However, with yarn2+ I am getting an error that says `Couldn't find a configuration settings named "version-git-message"`

My first question is, is it possible to set yarn version config options e.g. `version-git-message` and `version-commit-hooks` with yarn2+ ?

If not, how would I accomplish setting these version config options?

For reference, here are the scripts that I'm using in my CI pipeline

```
  - script: yarn config set version-git-message "v%s [skip ci]"
    displayName: 'tell the agent not to trigger a subsequent build after bumping the versions'
  - script: yarn config set version-commit-hooks false
    displayName: 'skip commit hooks'
  - script: yarn config set version-git-tag false
    displayName: 'skip commit tag'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like yarn2+ removed a lot of their built in utilities that integrate with other tools.  Where yarn 1 automatically created a git tag with the `version` script, yarn2+ doesn't do that, so the [git tag management scripts](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/version#toc-git-tags) from yarn1 are no longer around.
Yarn2 also uses a [plug-in architecture](https://yarnpkg.com/features/plugins), so to use the version tools you'll need to install the [version plugin](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/version)